# django memcached on red hat

Tags: django, centos, memcached, libmemcached

I have installed pylibmc, libmemcached and activated memcached in settings.py using location:/path/to/memcached.sock/

When i run the websiteg i get:
libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now i open an ssh shell, open python3.4, import pylibmc and play with it (using the a memcached session on port 11211) and it works great.

I tried to reinstall pylibmc using the option path for libmemcached but still same error. Im running out of options.

Here my config for cache:

```
{'BACKEND: 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.Py.           LibMCCache',
         'LOCATION':     '/path/to/memcached.sock/',
         'TIMEOUT': 500}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If libmemcached was installed from source and no modifications were done to configure it will place libmemcached.so.11 under /usr/local/lib. Just make a symbolic link to /usr/lib.

e.g: ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so.11   /usr/lib/libmemcached.so.11